# Get TAdvEdit.Text directly from procedure/function

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Hello i get error E2197: **[DCC Error] proj1.pas(34): E2197 Constant object cannot be passed as var parameter**:

```
unit proj1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, AdvEdit;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    AdvEdit1: TAdvEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure SetEditText(const instr: string; out outstr: string);
begin
  outstr := instr;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetEditText('Pippo', AdvEdit1.Text);
end;

end.
```

Of course, i can solve writing:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var sText: string
begin
  SetEditText('Pippo', sText);
  AdvEdit1.Text := sText;
end;
```

But when i have many AdvEdit, then it is hard. Then i ask, is possible solve the problem in some mode giving directly TAdvEdit.Text as parameter in mine procedure?
Thanks very much.

Comment: Why don't you use something like `procedure SetEditText(const Text: string; Edit: TAdvEdit);`

Comment: @TLama Why would you ever need such a function? Would it ever be worthwhile?

Comment: @David, when I would, I don't know, set the font color by the input text length or something. I know it's meaningless to just assign a text to a control this way.

Comment: TLama: the procedure necessary return a string. It is a procedure that i insert in a library and i need use base type (string, integer etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume that `Text` is a property. And you cannot pass a property to a `var` or `out` parameter. You can only pass variables to parameters of those kinds.

You'll need to find a different way to write your code. You've come up with one such idea, but  it seems needlessly complex to me. I cannot see anything simpler than:

```
AdvEdit1.Text := 'Pippo';
```

How could there be any code simpler than this? You need to specify at a bare minimum the following:

- The target control.
- That we are dealing with the `Text` property.
- The fact that we are assigning.
- The new value.

The code above does that and nothing more.

Comment: Hello David, thanks for answer; yes i understand; but the question was born from other. My form has almost 15 TAdvEdit control and i get value from a procedure (that return string and integer value). Ok about you told. But for me was strange that need write 15 or more line just only for assign a value declaring 15 variable for it. So, only for this i asked if was some other solution more "clean" . Thanks again.

Comment: I don't understand you. You didn't present the complexity in the question. For assigning a value to a property, there's nothing simpler than the code in my answer.